# python Raspberry pi receive udp data from spesefic port Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, udp, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I currently got my Raspberry Pi 3 working as a File-Sharing device on my local internet. A 5' display is connected to it and I want to be able to send commands to it through udp packets.
I know a lot about c#, but I'm totally new to python. I'm programming in Visual Studio.
I already have the sending program working coded in c#

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse(IPADDRESS);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 2522);
byte[] send_buffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TEXT);
sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);
```

I know it works becuase of my hard work with my UDP-Chat which is working.
Problem is, how do I receive it on my raspberry pi through python?
I tried:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.11" #Which is my local ip for my computer
UDP_PORT = 2522

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
   print (data)
```

But I got this message displayed when doing 'python Receiver.py':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Receiver.py", line 7, in <module>
    sock.bind(("192.168.1.11", UDP_PORT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I created a new one, called it test.py, put it in same folder and ran it. simple print "hello world!", and it worked like expected. 
Did I do something wrong here? do I need to install something extra for my RPi3? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed UDP_IP = "192.168.1.11" to UDP_IP = ""
Like so:

```
import socket

UDP_PORT = 2522
UDP_IP = ""

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
             socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print (data)
```

I tried UDP_IP = " " before, but it gave Visual Studio Red lines.. And so I changed it to UDP_IP = "", and it worked. That little space destroyed the code.